# Remember me - only username - in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security. I have a business rule that states the user is required to login each time they enter the site, but, if they check the Remember Me checkbox, their username will be be remembered between visits (and prepopulated in the form) and they are still required to enter their password and login.

Is something like this possible with the Remember Me functionality in Spring Security?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Remember me functionality of spring security is not meant for the use case you describe. Remember Me allows the user to go back to the site and be immediately logged in without user name or password.

This is because the user identity is defined by a REMEMBER_ME cookie that creates a new session upon submission, in case the user was not logged in and no session existed.

One way to implement remembering the username only and still force the user to type the password is to use a separate custom cookie that contains the username only.

The new cookie can either be created in the backend using the [servlet API addCookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29) method, on in the frontend using the [Javascript cookie APIs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: Should it not be done by javascript cookies instead? As spring security class has many methods like autoProcessLogin etc which are not required for this case.

Comment: Yes that's right, it's what I meant by a separate custom cookie - a cookie that is not managed by spring. You can create it both on the backend using the servlet API http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie) or some javascript on the frontend http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp as it's most convenient

Comment: Please share your answer, how did you implement this in spring application using servelt